# How to get last item from MsBuild Items?

Tags: msbuild

In my build script I have peace of code:

```
<CreateItem Include="src\packages\**\nunit-console.exe">
  <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="NUnitRunners"/>
</CreateItem>
```

It actually find all `nunit-console.exe` in my packages folder. Let it used something like this:

```
<Exec Command="&quot;@(NUnitRunners)&quot; ..." />
```

It works when only one `nunit-console.exe`, but obviously it just concatenates paths if more then one exits.

1. Is there any way to get last item from items collection
   (NUnitRunners in my case)?
2. Any other technics how to get path of
   latest nunit-console.exe in packages folder?

Answer (score 3):

This might be a bit hacky but you can use batching to extract the last item by just assigning `%(Items.Identity)` to a property.

Extracting the first item is a little trickier, you have to reverse the order of the original items by creating new items `<Reversed Include="@(Items->Reverse())" />`. Then you assign `%(Reversed.Identity)` to a property.

I'm not sure if this could break but looks good for me even when parallel builds are enabled.

See an example here: https://gist.github.com/shadow-cs/cb5499b010bdacd1f778be29daf7f04c

Answer (score 2):

You could try to create an `ItemGroup` instead and then to use `MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Framework.MsBuildHelper` to extract elements from it.

Some links:

- A similar question on MSDN: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/73d71e40-163a-4217-8e04-ce08fedefb69/how-to-extract-a-particular-item-from-an-itemgroup-in-msbuild.
- MsBuildHelper doc: http://www.msbuildextensionpack.com/help/4.0.8.0/?topic=html/d73eca07-8b36-919e-cbb6-ea1c17667dfe.htm.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to solve the exact same problem. I wrote an inline task which solves the problem:

```
<UsingTask TaskName="GetFirstItem" TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v12.0.dll">
  <ParameterGroup>
    <Items ParameterType="Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITaskItem[]" Required="true" />
    <FirstItem ParameterType="System.String" Output="true" Required="false" />
  </ParameterGroup>
  <Task>
    <Using Namespace="System.Linq"/>
    <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs">FirstItem = Items.First().ItemSpec;</Code>
  </Task>
</UsingTask>
```

See an example here: https://gist.github.com/Serivy/74fff320c93176e6ca7f76e1cc139367

But in the end I didn't want the overhead and settled for a error message if there were too many/not enough.

```
<Error Condition="@(NUnitRunners->Count()) != 1" Text="@(NUnitRunners->Count()) nunit runners found." />
```